# How to add bootstrap theme/example into ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project and i have to put bootstrap theme/example into the project and i dont know how. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/dashboard/. I have downloaded a .zip file on previous page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/ and i dont know how to use it in a project.

I cant find a tutorial that help to do that, i just find how to add theme. May someone know how to do it or a tutorial that can show me the way?

Thanks a lot